# No "Project" option in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create a new C project in VS. Earlier, I have been using it for Python codes and it worked fine but I want it to use for C code simultaneously with Python but there is no new "Project" option in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: VS is an IDE, and VSC is merely a text editor. So there is no project option in VSC.

Comment: Can I know what is your purpose actually? Do you want to switch between two different project easily? Is that your purpose?

Comment: Even after adding extensions for C/C++ it is not ruuning.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode does not have a project model like VS. Please see our documentation and getting started resources to understand how VS Code works:

- [General VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/)
- [Getting started videos](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/introvideos)
- [Python docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python)